# Using Google Cardboard with Unity I can set the autowalk on click but can't change directions when I look around

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm working on a 3D environment for Google Cardboard with Unity. I've used this tutorial as my base: http://danielborowski.com/posts/create-a-virtual-reality-game-for-google-cardboard/

I found a code snippet that allows me to trigger the autowalk on click:

```
void OnEnable(){
    Cardboard.SDK.OnTrigger += TriggerPulled;
}

void OnDisable(){
    Cardboard.SDK.OnTrigger -= TriggerPulled;
}
void TriggerPulled() {
    checkAutoWalk = !checkAutoWalk;
}
```

However, when I look around I keep walking in the original direction. Meaning I start walking forward but when I turn around I'm walking backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did something like this a year ago, don't know if this is still the right way to do it.

First I created a new script called Autowalk, attach this to the **Head** gameobject.

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    public class Autowalk : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public bool Triggered;
        private FPSInputController _fpsController;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start ()
        {
            _fpsController = GetComponent<FPSInputController>();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            // use Triggered to test in the inspector
            if(Cardboard.SDK.CardboardTriggered){
                _fpsController.checkAutoWalk = !_fpsController.checkAutoWalk;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My FPSController script looks like this, here I change the direction, depending on the direction I am facing and applying this to the CharacterMotor.

```
using UnityEngine;

// Require a character controller to be attached to the same game object

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    [RequireComponent(typeof (CharacterMotor))]
    [AddComponentMenu("Character/FPS Input Controller")]
    public class FpsInputController : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private CharacterMotor _motor;
        public bool CheckAutoWalk;

        // Use this for initialization
        private void Awake()
        {
            _motor = GetComponent<CharacterMotor>();
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        private void Update()
        {
            // Get the input vector from keyboard or analog stick
            Vector3 directionVector;
            if (!CheckAutoWalk)
            {
                directionVector = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
            }
            else
            {
                directionVector = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
            }

            if (directionVector != Vector3.zero)
            {
                // Get the length of the directon vector and then normalize it
                // Dividing by the length is cheaper than normalizing when we already have the length anyway
                var directionLength = directionVector.magnitude;
                directionVector = directionVector/directionLength;

                // Make sure the length is no bigger than 1
                directionLength = Mathf.Min(1.0f, directionLength);

                // Make the input vector more sensitive towards the extremes and less sensitive in the middle
                // This makes it easier to control slow speeds when using analog sticks
                directionLength = directionLength*directionLength;

                // Multiply the normalized direction vector by the modified length
                directionVector = directionVector*directionLength;
            }

            // Apply the direction to the CharacterMotor
            _motor.inputMoveDirection = transform.rotation*directionVector;
            _motor.inputJump = Input.GetButton("Jump");
        }
    }
}
```

GameObject structure and view of the inspector, with the attached scripts:

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD7tZ.png)
[inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJVz2.png)

If you have anymore question feel free to ask ;)

Cheers
Tobi